# "Some settings are managed by your organization" - No solution works

Tags: windows-10, updates, group-policy

I'm running Windows 10 Pro and trying to update to Windows 11, but I can't get rid of this pesky message:

> "Some settings are managed by your organization".

I've tried essentially all the possible solutions I've seen here:

- I'm not part of a domain and I have no work or school accounts.
- I can't changed diagnostic data settings, they're grayed out.
- Every setting in the group policy editor is "Not configured".

Responses to users:

I'm logged into my personal MS account.

My PC meets the requirements for 11 as far as I know. The Connected Users Experiences and Telemetry service IS running.

Screenshots:

[image: Diagnostics data]
[image: Update policies]

More suggestions:

- In the group policy editor > Adm. Templates > All Settings, everything is set to "Not configured". If these policies aren't there, I don't know where to find them.
- I activated the feedback and diagnostics settings and even managed to enable full and optional diagnostic data. Didn't work, except the message now doesn't appear in the feedback and diagnostics screen.
- "Device Management Wireless Application Protocol (WAP) Push message Routing Service" is now running. No difference.
- Now I only have one key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection, it's "(Default)" with a value not set.

[image]

- The Windows 11 installation assistant doesn't work, it tells me to use the PC Health Check app which just says that my organization manages updates.
- I created a local account and removed my MS account from every setting I could find. No difference.

Comment: Are you logged in with a Microsoft account by any chance?

Comment: If you are getting this message it means you have some required feature turned off like diagnostic data. Can you provide a screenshot of your Settings application that displays the message? Does your system meet the requirements for Windows 11? Is the *Connected User Experiences and Telemetry* service running? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Comment: “Every setting in the group policy editor is "Not configured".” - This is obviously not true since you have group policies set by an Administrator. So set the policies listed in your screenshot to “not configured”. Try enabling **Improve Inking and Typing** and **Tailored Experience** and reboot your machine. Also make sure **Device Management Wireless Application Protocol (WAP) Push message Routing Service** is running

Comment: What is the value of **Telemetry** key located at **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection** as always provide an [edit] to your question instead of submitting a comment.  If all else fails use the [Windows 11 Update Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11) to perform the update.  You will want to do that as an Administrator

Comment: I'm fairly sure the problem is that you are logged in using your microsoft account. If you convert it to a normal account, you probably can change the settings to what you want it to be, upgrade to windows 11 and login with your microsoft account again.